# PHP http_response_code($code) gets executed in a totally false if statement

Tags: php

Im developing an API in php, and i ran into a problem, basically `http_response_code(int $code);` behaviour is unpredictable, it just always gets sent at all costs if present anywhere in the code, and after that, naturally i cannot set another `http_response_code(int $otherCode)` as headers are already sent. I do not know what i am doing wrong, but i think i can boldly assume that `http_response_code(int $code);` can be used conditionally because it makes all the sense for me.
My question is, how this problem should be solved? I have to use the correct response codes, is there a working alternative which does not use rng to decide if it obeys an if statement?

PHP version is 7.4.5

smol version:

```
/* CASE 1 */
if(false){
     http_response_code(401);
     echo json_encode($someErrorMessage);
     die;
}
http_response_code(200);
echo json_encode($someResponse);
//Expectation: 200 response code & $someResponse json
//Result: 401 response with no message at all
```

```
/* CASE 2 */
if(false){
     //http_response_code(401);
     echo json_encode($someErrorMessage);
     die;
}
http_response_code(200);
echo json_encode($someResponse);
//Expectation: 200 response code & $someResponse json
//Result: 200 response code & json
```

Actual code:

```
try{
    if(empty(getallheaders()['Authorization'])){
        throw new WSException("oAuth access token missing from request");
    }
    $user = new Admin(getallheaders()['Authorization']);//Authenticate user, get data(throws WSException)
}
catch(WSException $e){    //Unauthenticated, send 401 header + message
    http_response_code(401);
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die;
}
/* GET USER DATA (SELF) */
#region GET USER DATA (SELF)
if($r == "get_self"){                               //Return user object as json

    try{
        /* BASIC DATA //$user already has all user data after authentication with `new Admin();` */
        if(!empty($user->profile_picture)){         //TODO: Function needed to filePHP
            $user->profile_picture = "{path/to/file.php}".$user->profile_picture;
        }
        http_response_code(200);
        echo json_encode($user, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);    //Unescaped slashes to send correct urls
        //An error cant really happen here rn, but when there is a possibility, it would be:
        //if($someError){
        //    http_response_code(401);
        //    throw new WSException("Something gone wrong");
        //}
    }catch(WSException $e){
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }           
    die;
}
#endregion
```

Comment: You could start by not scattering such calls all over your code, but rather **gather** data first and issue a single call to `http_response_code` at the latest possible position. Also, code like `if(false)` can be removed completely

Comment: I made a quick REPL of your demo code and it is returning the response correctly. https://3v4l.org/2SeKt

Comment: Are you saying that you can reproduce this issue with your CASE 1 and CASE 2 examples? Because I can't.

Comment: Actually i don't know why i did not think about that, i might have overcomplicated the thing for some reason, now i set the response code and the response in a variable and call it at the end of the code. Wrapped (almost) everything in a try-catch, put `http_response_code($code);` and `echo $response;` in a finally, rethrowing Exceptions in inner try-catches

Comment: What happened exactly is, in the "Actual code:" block, there was nothing catched, WSException logs errors into a file which were empty after the 401 response (in `__construct()`), but i still got the 401 response code, i commented the `//http_response_code(401);` part in the catch, tried the same request and it returned 200 with the user data.

Comment: Maybe `getallheaders()['Authorization']` is NOT empty?

Comment: I posted an answer, which explains why i thought if(false) was a good enough representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that `empty(getallheaders()['Authorization'])` returned true.

```
var_dump(empty(getallheaders()['Authorization']));
//Result: boolean: false
```

The thing is, if the value of `getallheaders()['Authorization']` is not used, or loaded into a variable, it's actually empty in an if statement

```
if(empty(getallheaders()['Authorization'])){
     //statement true, code gets executed
}
```

Solution:

```
if(empty($authHeader = getallheaders()['Authorization'])){
    //statement false, code does not get executed
}
```